# RestKit returns null value as "<null>" from JSON response

Tags: ios, xcode, json, restkit, nsuserdefaults

I have a weird bug in a JSON response I am getting from restkit.

I make a post request to the server and it responds with `"someVal" = "<null>"` instead of `"someVal" = null`. this causes xcode to deal with it in a very strange way and I cant seem to save it to NSUserDefaults because of it... and I cant remove it like I would a normal null value... what would it be detected as? I thought maybe a string? But nope... it cant save that as a string for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure that the value is stored as the string `"<null>"`? Because printing the description of a dictionary with a `[NSNull null]` value also produces the output `key = "<null>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this issue is limited to just RestKit. More from the server that is giving you the JSON. I have the same problem on my end using AFNetworking.

I found this Dictionary category that you can use to prune out the nulls and replace with empty strings. You can use that or just rip the logic out to sort through your null values.

```
@implementation NSDictionary (JRAdditions)

- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings {

    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for(NSString *key in self) {
        const id object = [self objectForKey:key];
        if(object == nul) {
            //pointer comparison is way faster than -isKindOfClass:
            //since [NSNull null] is a singleton, they'll all point to the same
            //location in memory.
            [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:replaced];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSMutableDictionary *replaced = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
    const id nul = [NSNull null];
    const NSString *blank = @"";

    for(NSString *key in dict) {
        const id object = [dict objectForKey:key];
        if(object == nul) {
            //pointer comparison is way faster than -isKindOfClass:
            //since [NSNull null] is a singleton, they'll all point to the same
            //location in memory.
            [replaced setObject:blank forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:replaced];
}

@end

// you can use this category on your dictionaries.
NSDictionary *jsonDict = JSON;
jsondict = [jsonDict dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithStrings];
```

Comment: this doesnt work for values that show as "<null>" as opposed to null for me anyway. I use this method for removing the standard nulls but it doesnt remove values that show as "<null>" when I NSLog the data feed.

Comment: It could be a string with that value. Maybe modify that method to replace the string <null> with an empty one.

Comment: it doesnt recognise "<null>" as a string type though which is weird.

Comment: That is odd. Then you are probably closer to my original answer then. You might need to debug that method to see what type your null is. Maybe tinker with it until you get it right.